# How do I read this code in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a script that was given to me for a certain reason to use, which is written in perl, and I have no idea how to read in perl. The only modification that I need to make to this program in order to run it is to enter the corresponding file name that the program will be using into the script, but I have no idea where the file name is supposed to go. Can you help me out?

I am assuming it's somewhere in one of these two blocks within the script:

```
die "usage : [fasta file] \n" unless (@ARGV);
```

OR here:

```
sub read_fasta {
     my ($data, $file)= @_;
     open(FILE, "<",$file) or return 0;
```

Comment: Why did you remove the Perl code? It's essential for understanding your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message the script produces when you provide no arguments seems to indicate you should provide a file name as an argument.

```
./script file.fasta
```

The code confirms it. The first of the script's arguments is moved into `$genome`, and passed to `read_fasta` which places it in `$file`, which it passes to `open` as the name of the file to open.

Comment: It confirms it's as I said.

Comment: Don't change code... your file to process is passed as 1st command line argument to script

Comment: You shouldn't be touching the code. You should be passing it as a command line argument as I showed. (Replace `./script` with the path to the script. Replace `file.fasta` with the path to the data file.)